# cmd 'patch' is not recognised as an internal/external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: cmd

I'm trying to patch my wordpress installation to protect from user enumeration.
I found a patch - [here](http://blog.hacktalk.net/block-wordpress-user-enumeration-secure-wordpress-against-hacking/)

It said to use it I need to navigate to the sites root folder, add the patch file then run it using cmd ,      `patch -p0 <wpuserEnum.patch`

When I hit enter I get the 'patch' is not recognised as an internal/external command, operable program or batch file' message

Not the most helpful error reporting. I have googled the problem all day and have not found any solutions regarding 'patch' specifically

I have checked PATH and there is a C:\Windows\System32 path there

Can anybody shed any light on what is happening and why?

I am running Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 7):

[patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_%28Unix%29) is not part of Windows so it won't be installed unless you install it yourself.  You can get it as part of the GnuWin32 project - http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/patch.htm

Comment: Thank you, that explains it! I will have a go with that link and get back to you. Much appreciatted

Comment: @user1750332 if this answers the question please mark my answer as accepted by checking the check mark.

Comment: No I'm still getting the same error message, assuming that I installed the patch from the above link correctly. Did i need to do anything else other than run the installer?

Comment: The installer doesn't add patch to your path automatically.  Try typing in the full path to where you installed it.  Probably either `C:\Program Files\GnuWin32` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32`.

Comment: Yes I have done that already, C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32. Still getting same error message

Comment: Did try `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin`?

Comment: Yes @shf301 I did try that a while ago. I tried it again this morning and it started to run the patch. Now I am getting 'Assertion failed: hunk, file ../patch-2.5.9-src/patch.c, line 354

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.'

Comment: Anyone? I'm beginning to panic now!

Comment: Problem sorted, I set up a VBox and did it in Linux and copied affected files back into Windows. Not that anyone seems to care! :)

Answer (score 6):

You need to edit your system environment variables, then add the path to patch.exe(in GnuWin32\bin) to the PATH environment variable...after restarting the cmd, patch should be recognized...

Comment: For me the path is `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`, after adding it, I needed to restart the PC for it to take effect.

Answer (score 3):

It helped me to run the next command:

```
npm i patch-package
```

(From here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package )

Answer (score 3):

I don't think GnuWin32 works for Win10 (at least they only mentioned Win7 in their website).
The safest way (works for me) is Git for Windows: https://git-scm.com/download/win
It has patch.exe in Git\usr\bin folder. Just add it to your path will work!